# adding a level as default value on Shiny select input

Tags: r, select, shiny

Suppose I hage some levels in a dataframe and I want to default the value to a certain level, so I tried this

```
selectInput('type', h4("some text"), c(levels(df$type)),value=as.factor(levels(df$type)[1])))
```

and I get this error message

```
ERROR: unused argument (value = as.factor(levels(df$type)[1]))
```

Of course, since `levels(df$type)[1]` is equal to some string `str`; I tried to put directly `value=as.factor(str))` but it errorred out the same way.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use instead of `value =`: `selected =`

So the full answer would be:

```
selectInput('type', h4("some text"), c(levels(df$type)),selected=as.factor(levels(df$type)[1])))
```

There is no such an argument in `selectInput` as `value`. Please refer to [this link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html).

**[UPDATE]**

```
selectInput('type', h4("some text"), choices=levels(df$type),selected=levels(df$type)[1]))
```

if you call levels, then your output is already a vector, there is no need to use `c()` after `level()`.

Additionally your `df$type` must already be a factor (because you use `levels()` argument)!Therefore you do not need to use `selected=as.factor(levels(...)[1]))`, instead use simply `selected=levels(...)[1]`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Now, trying your suggestion, I get this `Warning: Error in selectInput: argument 4 matches multiple formal arguments`

Comment: you should provide sample data (in your case it is `df`), without it i cannot say much....

Comment: i think i know what can be a problem, check my update

Comment: I cannot really understand what you mean, the best way would be to provide sample of your data...why it does not work?what kind of error do you get?